# Is this a sheaf isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory

Let $s_1$ and $s_2$ be disjoint codimension 1 subvarieties in a variety $X$. Let $i_1 : s_1 \to X$ and $i_2 : s_2 \to X$ be the respective immersions.

My question is whether there is an isomorphism,
$$
\mathcal{O}_X(s_1+s_2)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}i_{1*}\mathcal{O}_{s_1}
\cong
\mathcal{O}_X(s_1)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}i_{1*}\mathcal{O}_{s_1} \,.
$$
I would expect this to be true, since $i_{1*}\mathcal{O}_{s_1}$ only has support on $s_1$. But it seems to me that these two sheaves assign different objects to any open set intersecting both $s_1$ and $s_2$.

Comment: I don't understand, there is no mention about $i_2, s_2$ on the right hand side, is this a typo ?

Comment: @N.H. It's not a typo. My thought was that since $i_{1*}\mathcal{O}_{s_1}$ has support only on $s_1$, it doesn't 'see' that $\mathcal{O}_X(s_1+s_2)$ cares about $s_2$, since $s_2$ doesn't intersect $s_1$. Roughly my feeling is that tensoring with $i_{1*}\mathcal{O}_{s_1}$ should perform a kind of restriction to $s_1$.  I could also equally have asked whether
$
\mathcal{O}_X(s_1+s_2)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}i_{2*}\mathcal{O}_{s_2}
\cong
\mathcal{O}_X(s_2)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}i_{2*}\mathcal{O}_{s_2}
$.